# Evitar que elemento hijo se salga del elemento padre

Tags: css3, ccs

Tengo este código html:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-imagen">
    <img src="img/coliseo.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Y tengo este css:

```
.panel{
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.panel-imagen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.panel-imagen img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

El problema es que la imagen se sale del **div** `panel-imagen`, ya le he buscado mil formas y no he podido solucionar el problema.

Por que esta pasando esto? Como lo soluciono?

Comment: No revisaste que otros estilos más abajo pueda ser la causa? Porque así como está funciona bien

Comment: Todo respeta al padre `.panel` de 600 pixeles. Nadie sale de el

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz esos estilos son todos los que tengo de momento

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz y entonces por que la imagen no respeta las medidas de su contenedor?

Comment: Tu `.panel-imagen` es 100% de ancho, lo que viene ser el total de 600px del `.panel`. entonces tú imagen será de 600 pixeles

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz y como hago para que la imagen no se desborde?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo de cómo la imagen sobresale de su contenedor padre.

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 300px; 
 margin-top: 10px; 
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 padding: 10px 5px 0; 
 background-color: #fff; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 border: 1px solid #eee; 
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
 position: relative; 
}

.panel-imagen{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 300px; 
 margin-top: 30px; 
} 

.panel-imagen img{ 
 border-radius: 4px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"> 

<div class="panel-imagen"> 
 
 <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"> 
 
</div> 
   </div>
```

Y este ejemplo es como debería está bien:

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 300px; 
 margin-top: 10px; 
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 padding: 10px 5px 0; 
 background-color: #fff; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 border: 1px solid #eee; 
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
 position: relative; 
}

.panel-imagen{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 300px; 
 margin-top: 30px; 
} 

.panel-imagen img{ 
 width: 100%; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"> 

<div class="panel-imagen"> 
 
 <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"> 
 
</div> 
   </div>
```

Si de igual te surge algún problema, debe ser algo en HTML o CSS. A mí me funciona bien como también aquí.

Comment: A mi se me sigue desbordando y con todas las imágenes que he puesto pasa lo mismo

Comment: Bueno. Si no revisa bien tu código, seguirá el dolor de cabeza. Debe ser otro estilo en algún lado. Y si eso es todo tu código, entonces que pasa? Será mejor borrar todo y empezar de cero y bien cuidado, ya que es poco código y el único como dijiste

Comment: Sigue dando problemas, el ancho del padre si lo respeta pero el alto no